# Exclude subscribers from a location-based mobile push notification

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, mobilepush, mobilepush-android, mobilepush-ios

My client wants to send targeted location-based push notifications in order to send only relevant/appropriate messsages when a subscriber is near a location.

An example would be : Send a push notification about the "VIP service" to VIP clients when they enter a stadium. VIP is an attribute in the population of clients.

But from my understanding of this feature in mobile push, we cannot segment subscribers with the location-based template. Am I wrong ?

If I am wrong, I would prefer, how can we achieve this ? Audience Builder ? Exclusion scripts ?

Or maybe use the **RaiseError** function to block the send ? But I am not sure if it works with MobilePush. I know that this method will corrupt tracking data.

Answer (score 1):

You could [override notification](http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/notifications/override-notifications.html) handling and use a [custom key](http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/features/custom-keys.html) in your notification message to display VIP messages to appropriate audiences.

Comment: Thanks Bill for this solution but i am worrying about billing (Super Messages) as the message will be sent to all subscribers then filtered inside the app. 
The best solution for me would be to filter (segment) my audience before sending the gefencing message.

Comment: Geofence messages are downloaded rather than sent.  You are only billed for messages that are displayed.  Creating an audience list in the UI tells the servers which devices can download the message such that it is sitting ready to display the moment the consumer crosses the geofence boundary.

Comment: I believe Geofence messages don't use audience list in the UI but only a location. If I understand well you're point view and based on the last note in the official documentation [link](http://bit.ly/2yErDYO)  : If I use a AMPScript that returns no content or an empty string for "non VIP" customers based on an IF statement then I will be billed only for messages that are sent to VIP customers ?

Comment: I'm telling you that you _could_ override notification handling and swallow any message you don't want displayed and that you will be billed only for messages that are displayed.  See answer for links to relevant documentation.  It is also possible that you could use the empty AmpScript hack, but you should test it.